# Import JSDOC documentation from another file

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I import the documentation for class foo in File B?

```js
// FileA.js
/** This is a class */
class foo { }

export default objectThatContainsFoo // foo isn't directly exported
```

```js
// FileB.js
/** @typdef {--IMPORT DOCUMENTATION FOR foo--} foo */

/**
 * @param {foo} foo - This is a foo
 */
function bar(foo) { return true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way that ended up working for me is to make a quick `typedef` in the source file that can then be imported.

```js
// FileA.js

/** @typedef {foo} foo */

/** This is a class */
class foo { }

export default objectThatContainsFoo // foo isn't directly exported
```

```js
// FileB.js
/** @typdef {import("FilaA.js").foo} foo */

/**
 * @param {foo} foo - This is a foo
 */
function bar(foo) { return true }
```

Now foo's properties and descriptions can be seen in FileB